# Realm bad behavior in background thread

Tags: android, realm

Changes in the database from a background thread is displayed only after restart the application. Why? How to fix?

```
public class UILApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

In the background is next code inserting to DB:

```
public void setFollows(List<JSONObject> follows) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    List<Follow> finalFollows = new RealmList<>();

    try {
        for(JSONObject follow:follows){
            finalFollows.add(new Follow(follow.getLong("id"),follow.getString("username"), follow.getString("profile_picture"), follow.getString("full_name")));
        }
        List<Follow> goneFollows = getGoneFollows(finalFollows);
        List<Follow> newFollows = getNewFollows(finalFollows);

        realm.beginTransaction();

        if(goneFollows != null && !goneFollows.isEmpty()){
            goneFollows = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(goneFollows);
            L.d("getHistoryForUpdate goneFollows");
            History history = getHistoryForUpdate();
            history.getRemoveFollows().clear();
            history.getRemoveFollows().addAll(goneFollows);
        }

        if(newFollows != null && !newFollows.isEmpty()){
            newFollows = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newFollows);
            L.d("getHistoryForUpdate newFollows");
            History history = getHistoryForUpdate();
            history.getNewFollows().clear();
            history.getNewFollows().addAll(newFollows);
        }

        finalFollows = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(finalFollows);
        getFollows().clear();
        getFollows().addAll(finalFollows);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public History getHistoryForUpdate(){
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    String today = DateHandler.getOnlyDate();

    History history = realm.where(History.class).equalTo("createDate", today).findFirst();

    if(history == null){
        L.d("getHistoryForUpdate new");
        realm.beginTransaction();
        history = new History();
        history = realm.copyToRealm(history);
        history.setCreateDate(today);
        getHistoryList().add(history);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
    L.d("getHistoryForUpdate");
    realm.close();
    return history;
}
```

In Fragment trying to enter new data but I get only after you restart the application

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    favorite = realm.where(Favorite.class).equalTo("id", Long.parseLong(userId))
            .findFirst();
    RealmList<History> historyList = favorite.getHistoryList();
    ...
}
```

Inside background thread are all well written and have access to the data at once, but to get the data from the application, it must be restarted

Comment: It's hard to answer if you don't show us the code

Comment: @tim-castelijns added code)

Comment: Why do you expect it to reload data automatically? You only fetch historyList once and don't do anything with it

Comment: @tim-castelijns I forgot to put the dots and after I displaye in Listview of data follows

Comment: I'm pretty sure `getFollows().clear();` is deprecated, what version of Realm is this? By the way you're just most likely not registering a `RealmChangeListener` in which you'd call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter

Comment: @tim-castelijns I understand what you're saying, but I reboot Activity with fragment after write data in a background thread. So onCreateView called again, but database no change until the Application is not restarted. io.realm: realm-gradle-plugin: 1.0.0 using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<receiver
        android:name=".core.receivers.Alarm"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

Success came after removal of the second attribute

Comment: In that case, you ran into multiprocess inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, Realm currently doesn't support multiprocess access. It is being tracked here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1091